# Association rule using apriori function in R

Tags: r, apriori

Following is my code in R:

```
install.packages("arules")
install.packages("arulesViz")
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)
frq <- read.csv("E:/Uni/big data/A1_release_2018/A1_success_data.csv")
freq = as(frq,"transactions")
freq

rules <- apriori(freq,parameters=list(supp=0.1,conf=0.8,target="rules"))
inspect(rules)
```

I am getting the following error

```
Error in apriori(freq, parameters = list(supp = 0.1, conf = 0.8, target = "rules")) : 
  unused argument (parameters = list(supp = 0.1, conf = 0.8, target = "rules"))
```

I am new to R. I am applying apriori fn on a transaction object.I got this trasaction object by converting the .csv file. But  I am not able to apply apriori function on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just small modification in your code.

```
rules <- apriori(freq,parameter=list(supp=0.1,conf=0.8,target="rules"))
```

Second argument is **parameter** not **parameters**.